# ¿Ayuda con esquema HR de Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Bueno resulta que para mostrar la tabla empleados debo escribir esto:
SELECT * FROM HR.EMPLOYEES; , pero se que se puede omitir el HR.EMPLOYEES
quedando:
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES;

¿Que como lo soluciono?

Saludos a todos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que es hr? un esquema? si te paras en el esquema no lo necesitas

Answer (score 0):

hay dos aspectos principales que debes tener en cuenta para que un usuario realice una consulta a una tabla o vista de otro esquema, en este caso el HR, el primero es que el usuario que desea consultar tenga permisos de consulta sobre el objeto en efecto, los cuales debido a que realizas la consulta indicando el esquema.tabla supongo ya posees, y el segundo aspecto el cual te evita indicar el esquema es crear un sinónimo, el cual puede ser publico o privado, yo personalmente te recomiendo que sea privado con el fin de mantener un estándar de seguridad con mayores restricciones mediante una sentencia similar a esta:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM MI_USUARIO.NOMBRE_DESEADO FOR HR.NOMBRE_TABLA;
```

De esta forma podrás realizar la consulta sobre la tabla del esquema HR usando el NOMBRE_DESEADO asignado, el cual puede ser el mismo NOMBRE_TABLA teniendo la precaución de no tener actualmente un sinónimo con el mismo nombre, ya que esto provocaría que se sobreescriba.

Saludos.